Problem: Audio quality getting bad with fps rate changes to lower than 24 fps
total newbie here.
I am making a photo slideshow with an audio file.
I have around 23 photos set with 24 fps.
Suddenly, some of them change into lower than 24 fps, like 18.xx-22.xx fps and it seems like a warning sign, because the font colour changes into red.
When this happens, the audio quality is getting bad, it even appears to be slower.
The whole video is around 23 sec. long.
What can I do to improve the audio quality here?
I don't have the problems in the origional audio file.
I hope anyone could be of help.

Is this while watching it in playback while you're editing? Or is this when it's already exported as a video file?

Hello and thanks for your answer!
Well, unfortunately a slower video with a longer showing of the pictures is not what's suitable for the vibe of the slideshow. :(
If that is the reason, there won't be a solution for my problem.

It is while watching it in playback, I haven't it exported as a video file, good point! Thanks, I will try it out!

I think these links can help you out a bit: 1 2 3

Is there a reason you are using Blender to create a slide show?
